# RijndaelManaged: IV Generation?

Tags: c#, cryptography, rijndaelmanaged

I want to implement the most secure, and most reliable form of symmetric key cryptography in my application.  The user should input a password to encrypt/decrypt, and that's all.  For RijndaelManaged, one must enter a key and an IV. I'm not sure how to address the situation.  Right now, I have the entered password being hashed by SHA256 and then being used as the key for the Rijndael.  What do I use for the IV?  Another password?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`GenerateIV`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.generateiv.aspx) (overridden in `RijndaelManaged`) to generate the IV. You can then transmit the IV along with the cyphertext. You can think of an IV as acting a bit like a salt - basically it prevents the same plaintext from being encrypted to the same cyphertext each time. Don't reuse an IV - that makes it pointless. Generate a new one for each message.

Comment: Is there a specific standard on where how to append the IV to a cypher text?

Comment: Put it before the cipher. That way you can have decrypt in streaming mode.

Comment: Is it safe to prepend the IV to the cypher text? The attacker would know that the first, say 128 bits, of the message is the IV, and this shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: @Mystic The `IV` isn't secret; it's just used so that the same `Key` isn't used more than once alone.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is a special function to get a key from a password, I believe it is safer than a Hash. You may want to look up yhe Rfc2898DeriveBytes class. It needs a `Salt` and a Password.
2. It is an accepted practice to add the IV (and the Salt) unencrypted to the message.
3. If you create an instance of the Rijndaal class, it auto-generates a IV, the sender can just use that.

Answer (score 2):

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530621/rijndaelmanaged-iv-generation/2530643#2530643) is correct about the IV, but you also have a problem with the way you are deriving a key.

Just using a single round of SHA256 on the plaintext password is *not* secure.  It leaves the system open to a simple dictionary attack.

There is a class of functions that are designed to take a plaintext password and create a cipher key from them - these are "key derivation functions".  You should use one of these - [PBKDF2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898) is a good choice - to generate your key.  The `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class implements PBKDF2.

The KDF will require a salt, which is randomly generated each time and included along with the cipher text (just like the IV).